# How to add an exit option on my Pig Latin Translator (Python)

Tags: python

I have made a simple Pig Latin Translator in python for an assignment in school but was wondering how to put in an exit option? This is my code so far:

```
while True:

    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')

    statement = input('Please enter a word to translate: ')

    if statement in vowels:
        print(statement[0] + ('way'))
    else:
        print(statement[1:] + statement[0] + ('ay'))
```

Comment: where do you want to place the `exit` option

Comment: You can press `Ctrl-C` to exit a script.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use break to get out of a loop if the user types a keyword like "exit". The keyword 'break' will end the for or while loop the code is currently in. In your case, it can end the while True loop.

```
while True:

    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')

    statement = input('Please enter a word to translate: ')

    if statement == "EXIT":
        print ("Exiting program.")
        break

    if statement in vowels:
        print(statement[0] + ('way'))
    else:
        print(statement[1:] + statement[0] + ('ay'))**strong text**
```

It's case specific, so that's probably the easiest way to avoid clashing with someone wanting to just input the word exit.

For the sake of completeness you could also use sys.exit() to entirely quit the program. You need to also include import sys for this to work. It makes no difference here, but if you entirely want to end a program and not just the current loop it would be useful.

```
import sys
while True:

    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')

    statement = input('Please enter a word to translate: ')

    if statement == "EXIT":
        print ("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit()

    if statement in vowels:
        print(statement[0] + ('way'))
    else:
        print(statement[1:] + statement[0] + ('ay'))**strong text**
```

Comment: Thanks a heap. Now I know for future programs :D

Comment: Well yes, for the sake of completeness you could also use `sys.exit()` to entirely quit the program (you need to also include `import sys` for this to work). It makes no difference here, but if you entirely want to end a program and not just the current loop it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter` with a sentinel value of an empty string, the user just hitting enter will exit the loop , you should also declare vowels outside the loop:

```
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}
for statement in iter(lambda: input('Please enter a word to translate '
                                'or hit "enter" to exit: '),""):
    if statement in vowels:
        print(statement + 'way')
    else:
        print(statement[1:] + statement[0] + 'ay')
```

You also use `if statement in vowels:print(statement[0] + 'way')`, if statement is in vowels it can only be  a single letter so indexing is pointless.